# Создание Shell Extentions

Tags: c#, файлы, ntfs

**Здравствуйте, Уважаемые Хэшкодовцы!**

Благодаря Вам узнал об альтернативных потоках данных для файлов на NTFS системе. Благодаря интернету научился с ними работать через командную строку. Может кому интересно:

```
echo some file > file.txt
```

создали/перезаписали информацию в файлу *"file.txt"* текстом *"some file"*

```
echo some description > file.txt:desc
```

создали/перезаписали альтернативный поток с именем *"desc"* для файла *"file.txt"*

```
more < file.txt
type file.txt
```

отобразили в окне консоли информацию содержащейся в файле *"file.txt"*. В нашем случае *"some file"*

```
more < file.txt:desc
```

отобразили в окне консоли информацию из альтернативного потока с именем desc.

```
dir /r
```

отобразили список всех файлов в текущем каталоге с их альтернативными потоками

---

В общем выше была лирика, это может кому пригодится. Теперь собственно сам вопрос:

### Как реализовать окно свойств, которое отобразит данные из альтернативного потока

В интернете нахожу много информации, как реализовать свою `Shell Extentions`. Но информации очень много на английском языке (или я просто не могу найти аналогичной информации на русском), что сильно затрудняет поиски решения с моими познаниями "вражеского" языка. Многие примеры рассказывают как перехватить выполнение команды, как добавить в контекстное меню файлов свои пункты, но это все не то. Мне нужно открыть окно свойств файла, в открывшемся окне свойств добавить свою закладку с конкретным именем, на закладке расположить компонент позволяющий просматривать текстовую информацию (ну пусть скажем это будет `RichTextView`) ну и поместить туда информацию из альтернативного потока с конкретным именем.

Как читать информацию из альтернативного потока примеры я нашел, думаю разберусь самостоятельно, а вот реализацией персональной закладки свойств для файла - увы не получается. На всякий случай уточню, расширений файлов будет несколько, для которых данное окно свойств должно появиться (ну например это будут `.ex1, .ex2`), и если есть такая возможность, окно свойств не отображать, в случае если альтернативного потока данных с нужным именем отсутствует у файла).

Забегая немного вперед, хотел бы еще возможность отображать окно свойств для нескольких выбранных файлов, но с этим сначала попробую сам разобраться.

Что собственно хочу от вас?

- Желательно ссылку на документацию по моей проблеме. Как я понял, махинаций которые можно вытворять при помощи `Shell Extentions` навалом, человеку который этим никогда не занимался - темный лес.
- Если есть конкретный пример подобной реализации на c# - буду признателен. Желательно конечно, чтобы код не был навороченным, достаточно самых основ, далее будем плясать от печки по принципу удочки.
- Ну и самое "здоровское" для меня, как для начала изучения проблемы - это подсказка, с чего начать писать модуль? Какие интерфейсы должны быть реализованы?

PS: Если все это будет еще и на русском языке - вообще вам цены не будет =)

**Заранее спасибо, что дочитали все это до конца, и за ваши ответы.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В силу ряда проблем Microsoft не рекомендует писать расширения для обозревателя с помощью управляемого кода и не планирует поддерживать разработку подобных расширений.

На неуправляемом коде добавление страницы свойств происходит согласно руководству (на 
английском): [How to Register and Implement a Property Sheet Handler for a File Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127448(v=vs.85).aspx).

Если все же браться за расширение на C#, то в качестве исходной точки можно взять готовый проект на C# (на английском): [Property Sheet Shell Extension in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8065/Property-Sheet-Shell-Extension-in-C).

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема уже давно решена. Могу дать пример. [AltStreamOverlay (с исходным кодом)](http://www.benf.org/other/alternatestreamoverlay/index.html)